# cURL request getting wrong request version in Google App Engine

Tags: php, json, google-app-engine, curl

I have a cURL request in my code which works fine when running locally:

```
$url = "http://ipinfo.io/{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$locale = json_decode($response);
```

and returns a JSON as expected. Our production system is on Google App Engine, however, where I get the website version for a browser rather than the JSON.

I can get this cURL request to work if I change

```
google_app_engine.enable_curl_lite = "1"
```

in the `php.ini` in the root directory of my project to

```
extension = "curl.so"
```

but Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/php_ini) insists the former is to be used on production. Additionally, using the latter breaks things like Monolog's SlackHandler.

Is there a way to get the JSON from this cURL request while still using Google's "cURL Lite"?

Comment: Maybe try setting a blank user-agent or setting it to something less likely to be considered a browser?  When I run your code from my command line, I get the JSON as expected.  When I explicitly set the user-agent to something recognizable as a browser, I get the HTML.

Comment: @PatrickQ Thanks! I found help elsewhere and posted answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the ipinfo.io documentation:

> "We do a little bit of magic on the server to determine if we should send the JSON response or the webpage. We usually get it right, but if you're seeing the webpage instead of the JSON (or want to check the JSON output in a browser) you can force the JSON response by adding /json to the end of the URL"

Adding `/json` to the end of the URL worked for me in this case, but I wanted a more general solution. Since Google's cURL Lite uses their [URL Fetch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/urlfetch/) in the background, ipinfo.io's "magic" is somehow getting confused. I found that by specifying the `Accept` header then the `/json` addition wasn't required. In PHP:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
```

Thanks to the folks on the [#php](https://nashdev.slack.com/messages/php/) channel of NashDev Slack for helping me on this one!